# How can i generate a databasediagram in Oracle Application Express?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex, database-diagram

I need to generate a database diagram automatically from a database script I have.

I have run the sql script and it worked. Right now I need to generate a database diagram using the script I ran.

I am working with **Oracle Application Express** web based and I googled it but I couldn't find anywhere how to do it. Does anyone know how I can generate automatically a database diagram with the SQL script I have in Oracle Application Express.

Below is my dashboard where do I need to click to generate my database diagram automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

APEX does not create a database diagram as you describe. Instead, you should use [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html), which is a free tool for creating and editing SQL And PL/SQL and Oracle database structures. Included with SQL Developer is a [Data Modeler](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html) that can reverse engineer a database connection to generate diagrams.